# Solving DDE in Matlab

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I am trying to learn how to solve DDE (delay diff. eq) on Matlab and I am using a very helpful ([Youtube-tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCWrD3cZG9s&list=LL&index=15)) where the guy solves examples. In the case of a 3-dimensional system, the code goes as follows:

```
tau = [1 0.5];
tf = 10;
sol = dde23(@dde,tau,@history,[0 tf]);
t = linspace(0,tf,200);
y = deval(sol,t);

figure(1)
plot(t,y)

function y = history(t)
y = [1;0;-1];
end
```

The `dde` function according to the tutorial is:

```
function dydt = dde(t,y,tau)
y1tau1 = tau(:,1);
y2tau2 = tau(:,2);
dydt = [y1tau1(1)
    y(1) - y1tau1(1) + y2tau2(2)
    y(2) - y(3)];
end
```

, where if I get it well, we have a 3by2 matrix with the state variables and their respective delays: the first column is about the first delay tau_1 for each of the three state variables, and the second column is for the tau_2.
Nevertheless, this matrix has only 2 non-zero components and they are the tau_1 delay for y_1 and the tau_2 for y_2.
Given that, I thought it would be the same (at least in this case where we only have one delay for y_1 and one for y_2) as if the function were:

```
function dydt = dde(t,y,tau)
dydt = [tau(1)
    y(1) - tau(1) + tau(2)
    y(2) - y(3)];
end
```

I ran the script for both of them and the results are totally different, both qualitatively and quantitatively, and I cannot figure out why. Could someone explain the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y1tau1(1)` and `y2tau2(2)` are `tau(1,1)` and `tau(2,2)`

while

`tau(1)` and `tau(2)`  are the same as `tau(1,1)` and `tau(2,1)`.

So the second one is different, there is no reason why the two different, if only slightly so, DDE systems should have the same solutions.

---

As you have also a general interpretation question, the DDE system is mathematically

```
dy1(t)/dt = y1(t-1)
dy2(t)/dt = y1(t) - y1(t-1) + y2(t-0.5)
dy3(t)/dt = y2(t) - y3(t)
```

It is unfortunate that the delayed values are also named `tau`, it would be better to use something else like `yd`,

```
function dydt = dde(t,y,yd)
  dydt = [ yd(1,1)
           y(1) - yd(1,1) + yd(2,2)
           y(2) - y(3) ];

end
```

This `yd` has two columns, the first is the value `y(t-tau(1))=y(t-1)`, the second column is `y(t-tau(2))=y(t-0.5)`. The DDE function does not know the delays themselves, it only computes with the values at these delays. These are obtained from a piecewise interpolation function that continues the history function with the solution so far. The history function takes the place of the initial condition.

Comment: But what is the difference between tau(2,2) and tau(2,1)? I know that they are included in different matrices but there are only two values of time-delays in both cases. Does the second version of the function imply that one of the two delays is 0?

Comment: In other words, I was considering that tau(2,2)=tau(2,1). Are there other calculations that Matlab does which might make the results different?

Comment: I understood my mistake. I was considering that the function takes directly the values of lags which it doesn't. Thanks a lot!